Helidon MP EntityManager always return NULL
I am facing a NullPointerException when trying to use EntityManager in my Helidon MicroProfile project. The exception occurs because the EntityManager is null when I attempt to create a query. The error message is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String, java.lang.Class)" because "this.entityManager" is null
This happens in the method getDataBaseData() of my DataBaseService class. I am using the @PersistenceContext annotation to inject the EntityManager, but it seems that the injection is not working as expected.
I am using Helidon MP, and I have configured the persistence.xml for Derby as the database.
here is ressources/META-INF/beans.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_4_0.xsd"
       version="4.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>

ressources/META-INF/persistence.xml :
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence
                                 https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">
    <persistence-unit name="explanationsDbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description> explanation database persistence unit </description>
        <jta-data-source>explanationsDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>fr.uge.xplain.Explanation</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

ressources/application.yaml :
javax:
  sql:
    DataSource:
      explanationsDS:
        driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource
        url: jdbc:derby:memory:explanations;create=true
        user: admin
        password: admin

Explanation (the Entity) :
package fr.uge.xplain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class Explanation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  // Option pour une meilleure compatibilité
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "source_code", length = 255)
    private String sourceCode;

    @Column(name = "explanations", length = 255)
    private String explanations;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private LocalDate creationDate;

    // Getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSourceCode() {
        return sourceCode;
    }

    public String getExplanations() {
        return explanations;
    }

    public LocalDate getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setSourceCode(String sourceCode) {
        this.sourceCode = sourceCode;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setExplanations(String explanations) {
        this.explanations = explanations;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDate creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
}

DataBaseService.java :
package fr.uge.xplain;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DataBaseService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "explanationsDbPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Explanation> getDataBaseData() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Explanation e ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC", Explanation.class)
                .getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void setDataBaseData(Explanation explanation) {
        entityManager.persist(explanation);
    }
}

DataBaseResource (POST & GET for fornt-end) :
package fr.uge.xplain;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/database")
public class DataBaseResource {

    @Inject
    private DataBaseService dataBaseService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDatabaseData() {
        List<Explanation> data = dataBaseService.getDataBaseData();
        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                    .entity(Map.of("message", "No data found"))
                    .build();
        }
        return Response.ok(data).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addData(Explanation explanation) {
        dataBaseService.setDataBaseData(explanation);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
    }
}


Is the @PersistenceContext annotation being used incorrectly?
How can I ensure that the EntityManager is injected properly in a Helidon MicroProfile project?
Are there any additional configurations needed to make the EntityManager work with CDI and Helidon?


Please see the persistence guide, which will walk you through every aspect of it. I've chosen Helidon v4 since you didn't indicate which version you were using.

Hello @LairdNelson, thank you for the advice but i have been through the guide multiple times but still get the error.

Update : I juste forgot to include JPA dependency !
As specified in Helidon MP documentation :
Helidon MP documentation 
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.helidon.integrations.cdi</groupId>
     <artifactId>helidon-integrations-cdi-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
